# How to un-hide relationship lines in mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, hide, show-hide, mysql-workbench

I'm working with mysql workbench v6.0

I can't seem to figure out how to un-hide relationships that I hide earlier.

Does anyone know how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only way but it works for me.

- Double click the table with the foreign key
- Click on the "Foreign Keys" tab at the bottom
- Select your your key then uncheck and re-check the checkbox for the column

Comment: Still works for me with mysql workbench 8.0.17 on mac.

Comment: Oh. I just tried in Ubuntu 18.04 using Mysql Workbench 6.3.8 build 1228 CE, which is the latest available in the repo. I might have to try and see if i can get version 8 then. Thanks!